# Azure AD - How to get groups with cloud source

Tags: .net, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I created multiple groups inside Azure AD, some of them are server source and the rest are cloud source.

Inside the token claims, I'm getting only the groups with server source, and not the groups with cloud source.

I didn't find any config option for returning from both sources.

How can I get the groups from all the sources?

Comment: Please refer [Get-AzureADGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadgroup?view=azureadps-2.0)

Answer (score 0):

***To get the groups from all the sources, use the below powershell command***

```cs
Get-AzureADMSGroup
```

[image]

- You can also add parameters

Please refer MSDoc  [Link1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadmsgroup?view=azureadps-2.0) and [Link2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadgroup?view=azureadps-2.0) for more information.